# Wpf Grid Search with large number of rows

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have grid view, with multiple columns and rows. this grid view is bind to the List  that has item number, Name, Description  etc... (same item and its number can be repeated more then one in Grid.) One of row of grid has Bar-code image of product number.
My problem is, 
when i scan the barcode and search the Grid for that number. i have to go through all the rows of grid. when there are large number of rows (ex-500) Application become slow.
How can i increase the search speed??
please help me if you know some solutions for this.

Comment: Post some relevant code and XAML.

Comment: @HighCore :Sorry but Because of some company security issue i cant post code or XAML here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution of my problem.

Using Lists ** Binary search method and maximum user of Dispatcher** is the best way to increase search speed.
Thank You.